# How to replace some value on a file using python?

Tags: python

```
    config firewall policy
        edit 1
            set name "[PROD] xxxx"
            set uuid xxxx
            set srcintf "A-LAN-GF" "A-LAN-01" "A-LAN-02" "A-LAN-03" "A-LAN-05" "A-LAN-06" "A-LAN-07"
            set dstintf "User-Outside"
            set action accept
            set srcaddr "Segment User"
            set dstaddr "[PROD] Rocket Terminal Emulator"
            set schedule "always"
            set service "[PROD] Rocket Terminal Emulator"
            set logtraffic all
        next
        edit 2
            set name "Active Defense-1"
            set uuid xxxx
            set srcintf "A-LAN-GF" "A-LAN-01" "A-LAN-02" "A-LAN-03" "A-LAN-05" "A-LAN-06" 
            set dstintf "User-Outside"
            set action accept
            set srcaddr "Segment User"
            set dstaddr "Active Defense-1"
            set schedule "always"
            set service "Active Defense-1"
            set logtraffic all
        next
        edit 3
            set name "xxx Development"
            set uuid xxxx
            set srcintf "A-LAN-GF" "A-LAN-01" "A-LAN-02" "A-LAN-03" "A-LAN-05" "A-LAN-06" "A-LAN-07"
            set dstintf "User-Outside"
            set action accept
            set srcaddr "Segment User"
            set dstaddr "ADFS Development"
            set schedule "always"
            set service "ADFS Development"
            set logtraffic all
        next
    end
```

I have some data which is saved on .txt file type. I have to replace the edit 1; edit 2; and edit 3 with edit 50; edit 51; and edit 52. Is someone know how to open .txt file and replace some value on that file by using python programming language?

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Please, show what have you tried ([mre]) and ask specific question about problem with your code. The answer to your question is YES.

Comment: You can't insert things into a file – you can only add to them at the end – so you can only overwrite with the same number of characters. Read the entire file, do the replacement, then save the entire file.

Comment: ^
You can certainly replace text in a file with new text that is a different length than the original text. This is incorrect info.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. You can try this code:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Read the contents of the file
    contents = file.read()

contents = contents.replace('edit 1', 'edit 50')
contents = contents.replace('edit 2', 'edit 51')
contents = contents.replace('edit 3', 'edit 52')

with open('filename.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(contents)
```

If you want, you can include some print statements, such as if a string was not found or there was another error in the program.